# Unable to click background components because upper z-index div margin is spread horizontally

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have 3d canvas with z-index : -1
I want to display components on z-index: 0 and be able to click 3d canvas without any problems. Unfortunately when I add component A to z-index: 0 margin of this component is spread horizontally and I'm unable to click 3d canvas one the left and right side of component A.

```css
.background-3d-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: silver;
}
    
.front-component {
    background-color: blue;border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-3d-canvas">
    <a href="#">Test</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Test2</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Test3</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Test4</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Test5</a><br/>
    <a href="#">Test6</a><br/>
</div>
    
<div class="front-component">
   Editor
</div>
```

I created jsfiddle to demonstrate this problem. Not all links are clickable.

https://jsfiddle.net/ec5uuthy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add those attributes to .front-component:

```
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/76bpqge1/